# replace name with id in mysql insert stement

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
persons(person_id, date_entered, first_name, country_id)

countries(country_id, country_name)
```

Country_id from countries is a foreign key in country_id in persons.

I have a POST form that asks for a persons name and nationality, then enters the information into the persons table. The nationality field is a lookup from the countries table and present a dropdown list of country names to the user. The submit button would send the data to the persons table.

The issue is, the nationality dropdown list produces a country name but I actually have to send that countries' id into the persons table. I am thinking I need to pull the data from the countries table and match the country_name to the nationality field and then extract the id but not sure...

Finally the question is, how do I match the country name from the dropdown list to its id and put that into the INSERT query?

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance!

Below is the non-working code I want to use to send the data to the DB:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$data_missing = array();

if(empty($_POST['first_name'])){
$data_missing[] = 'First Name';
} else {
$f_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
}

if(empty($_POST['nationality'])){
$data_missing[] = 'Nationality';
} else {
$nationality = trim($_POST['nationality']);
}

if(empty($data_missing)){

require_once('includes/db.php');

$get_countries = "SELECT * from countries";

$query = "INSERT INTO persons (candidate_id, date_entered, first_name, country_id) VALUES
(NULL, NOW(), ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

//  i Integers
//  d Doubles
//  b Blobs
//  s Everything Else

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $f_name, $nationality);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
if($affected_rows == 1){
$a="Candidate added!";
echo
"<script>alert('$a'); window.location.href='addcandidate.php';</script>";

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

mysqli_close($dbc);

}
} else {

echo 'You need to enter the following data<br />';

foreach ($data_missing as $missing) {

echo "$missing<br />";
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: in the select html use the id as value of the option and the name as text of the option. User will choose a name but will post and id

Comment: Hi Lelio, is this the line you speak of? echo "<option value ='$country_id'>$country_name</option>"; is this correct od do I need to add anything?

Comment: This is correct. If for some reason you can't use the ids in your select-box, you could use a subselect in your insert: INSERT INTO persons VALUES (...., (SELECT country_id from countries where country_name = ?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating your **Country** dropdown as follows:

```
<?php
  $countries = "SELECT * from countries";
  $results = $mysqli->query($sql);

  echo "<select name='country_code'>";
  foreach($result->fetch_assoc() as $row){
    echo "<option value='".$row['country_id']."'>".$row['country_name']."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

Then when you get the value of `$_POST['country_code']`, it will be the country id from your country table.

Comment: Thanks coderodour, that's what I have already and I think Lelio has pointed my in the right direction. Radicarl suggestion would be the long workaround if I couldn't get this to work. Off to test and will reply when done. Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Great. Also a point to note: if you use the above method, you do not need to do any comparisons for countries after submitting the form, you already know you you have the correct country id in your post variable and can save directly to person table.

Comment: Thanks @Coderodour, i already had everything in place but wasn't aware until you mentioned it. After this I had some errors but I resolved everything by putting this or 'die(mysqli_error($con));' at the end of my mysqli_prepare statement. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid exposing the country id's in the client side,
you can modify the INSERT query to include the appropriate country id:

*INSERT INTO persons (date_entered, first_name, country_id) 
VALUES (NOW(), ?, (SELECT country_id FROM countries WHERE country_name=?));*

Note that **candidate_id** in the insert query should be **person_id**.

Comment: Well spotted Java guy! Your answer, albeit it would work is a roundabout way and I already had everything in place to use the previous answer. Thanks for your help!